# Optimización consultas UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy intentando reducir el número de consultas a BD en un proceso que estoy haciendo, este proceso cada X tiempo tendrá que hacer un gran número (del orden de 4000 - 8000) de INSERT o de UPDATE.

La parte de los INSERT ya la he conseguido reducir agrupandolos en consultas de 1000 inserciones de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO hist_proceso(pc, fecha_comp, resultado, historico) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?) ........ ;
```

Consiguiendo de esta forma reducir de 4000-8000 inserts a solo 4-8.

El problema lo estoy teniendo a la hora de intentar hacerlo con los UPDATE ya que no puedo gastar una consulta como la siguiente:

```
UPDATE hist_proceso SET resultado=0, historico='aa';
```

Ya que cada elemento a actualizar tendrá unos valores distintos.

La columna de "resultado" podrá tener un valor de {0,1} 
y en la columna "historico" se irán concatenando los valores de esta forma : HH:mm/0;HH:mm/1;HH:mm/0;HH:mm/0;

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Puedes hacer algo como : Update Tabla set col 1= 1 , col2 = 2  where col3 = x, Asi los cambias del tiron. No se si ya lo has probado o algo, pero asi a bote pronto es lo que se me ocurre

Comment: @urrutias el problema es que no todos los registros a actualizar van a tener el mismo valor

Comment: @Joacer,  sólo has puesto un ejemplo de `UPDATE`, así que no sé qué campos se pueden agrupar ni cuáles componen la clave primaria (lo óptimo sería usarlos en el `IN`). Te dejo una respuesta con una alternativa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por desgracia sólo puedes optimizar los `INSERT`s de esa manera, los `UPDATE` sólo podrás optimizarlos agrupando por asignaciones.

Es decir:

```
UPDATE hist_proceso SET resultado = 0 WHERE historico IN ('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')
UPDATE hist_proceso SET resultado = 1 WHERE historico IN ('ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh')
```

De modo que asignarás 0 al campo `resultado` a todos los registros cuyo campo `historico` valga 'aa', 'bb', 'cc' y 'dd' y el valor 1 a los registros cuyo campo `historico` sea 'ee', 'ff', 'gg' y 'hh'.

He reducido ocho consultas a sólo dos con este tipo de agrupación.

También se podría usar un [`UPSERT`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT) o [`INSERT ... ON [CONFLICT] DO UPDATE ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

```
INSERT INTO hist_proceso (pc, fecha_comp, resultado, historico)
ON DUPLICATE KEY DO UPDATE
  pc = EXCLUDED.pc,
  fecha_comp = EXCLUDED.fecha_comp,
  resultado = EXCLUDED.resultado,
  historico = EXCLUDED.historico
VALUES
  (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?),
  (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?) ........ ;
```

Pero debes asegurarte que la clave primaria está compuesta por los campos adecuados y debes excluirlos del `DO UPDATE`.

Durante la inserción se crea una tabla llamada `EXCLUDED` donde se almacena temporalmente los valores que no se han insertado para ser usados durante la actualización. En este caso actualizamos con los nuevos valores e ignoramos los antiguos.

Comment: Me gusta mucho esta idea @OscarGarcia , ya que en mi caso el resultado sera o 0 o 1 ,  el Where será por otro campo, pero voy a intentarlo de esta forma

Comment: Acabo de actualizar con los campos a modificar y los valores q tendrán

Comment: Nada, veo que postgresql no soporta REPLACE, pero sí el INSERT con el modificador ON CONFLICT..

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar estas formas, porque he visto esta otra forma en SO inglés https://stackoverflow.com/a/20224370/3683321 y no me gusta

Comment: Respuesta editada. Comprueba si te funciona.

Comment: He probado el primer método y me ha ido perfectamente! Muchísimas gracias! El segundo método aun no lo he probado, pero mirare a ver que tal va